# Initializing ES6 module project with npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-modules, npm-init

Is there a way to have `npm init` directly set up an ES6 module, setting `"type":"module"` in *package.json* (or another `npm` command to set it)?

I always just modify *package.json* manually and add it, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do it directly with `npm` on the command line so I don't have to keep doing that. Just a convenience thing. Plus if I can do it with `npm` it's easier to automate.